# OpenNI2Driver, No matching device found

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, openni2, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

EDIT 3:

The issue returns if the package is launched in  superuser mode.

---

Hello all,

I have just installed ROS Indigo on my turtlebot PC having Ubuntu 14.04.02 which was just upgraded from Ubuntu 12. Earlier the turtlebot PC had Hydro. The problem I am describing hence was not present in the hydro installation.

On running,

`roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch` ,

I am getting the following error:

```
[ INFO] [1455122966.352999612]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
[ INFO] [1455122968.132593659]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: std::string openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Driver::resolveDeviceURI(const string&) @ /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-openni2-camera-0.2.5/src/openni2_driver.cpp @ 631 : Invalid device number 1, there are 0 devices connected.
```

I have tried the following solutions:

`roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch`            :    Does not work

https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/issues/139    :    Does not work

I also tried installing all sorts of drivers for the Kinect on turtlebot. The kinect works on other software giving me RGB as well as Depth sensing but still gmapping or any node requiring Kinect is ROS does not work probably because ROS Indigo uses OpenNi2 and not the driver I tested my kinect.

Thanks for the read.

EDIT_1:

I just got hold of this page regarding migration of turtlebot from Hydro to Indigo

http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TurtleBot/indigo/Migration

Though I have set up the environment variable `export TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR=kinect` in my `~/.bashrc` file, I do not know how to update to the new driver and get any calls from the existing ROS packages like `gmapping` to stop looking for OpenNI2.

EDIT_2:

Should I do a source install because the deb install is still calling OpenNi2 drivers instead of Freenect for Kinect?

Is there a way to substitute OpenNI2 drivers with freenect, or any working driver in `turtlebot_navigation` package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226236/openni2driver,-no-matching-device-found/) by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2016-02-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-02-11**:
Are you trying to use rgbdslam on the turtlebot? Does freenect-regview work for you? You can download it with `sudo apt-get install libfreenect-lib`

**Comment by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on 2016-02-11**:
I had already installed using `sudo apt-get install freenect` and the above command gives the output  `Unable to locate package libfreenect-lib`. I tried to launch `roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch` and this calls OpenNI2 not freenect, hence installing it did not help.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-02-11**:
Have you tried this: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-indigo-openni-camera ros-indigo-openni-launch` ?

**Comment by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on 2016-02-11**:
Reinstalling drivers helped. It does not show the OpenNI driver error now. But it shows some other warnings and errors that also came up when I was testing with the freenect. Nevertheless, gmapping works fine as seen in rviz. Thanks for the answer.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-02-19**:
You should ask a new Question for your update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try;

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-indigo-openni-camera ros-indigo-openni-launch`

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2016-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on 2016-02-11**:
Thank you!